# C++ substring not giving me the correct result

Tags: c++, string, substr

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file;
    string s;
    //file contains the following
    //id="123456789"
    //Note: There is no spaces at the end
    file.open("test.txt", ios::in);
    getline(file, s);
    s = s.substr(s.find("\"")+1, s.length()-1);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The results print:

```
123456789"
```

Why is there a quote at the end?
A weird thing is that when I change s.length()-1 to s.length()-5, the code work how I wanted it to.
What is the problem here?

Comment: Did you read any documentation that describes what the arguments to `substr` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of [`string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) is a *count*, not an *index*, like you are treating it.

In your example, `s.length()=14`, so you are asking for `14-1=13` characters starting at the index `+1` past the 1st `"` character (`3+1=4`), but there are only 10 characters remaining from that position onward.  That is why the 2nd `"` character is being included in the substring.

Use `string::find()` again to find the index of the 2nd `"` character, and then subtract the two indexes to get the length between them, eg:

```
auto start = s.find('\"') + 1;
auto stop = s.find('\"', start);
s = s.substr(start, stop-start);
```

`start` will be the index `+1` past the 1st `"` character (`3+1=4`), and `stop` will be the index of the 2nd `"` character (`13`).  Thus, the length you get is `13-4=9` characters.

---

Another way to handle this would be to put the `string` into an `istringstream` and then use the [`std::quoted`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/quoted) I/O manipulator to extract the substring between the `"` characters, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("test.txt");
    string s;
    getline(file, s);
    istringstream iss(s);
    iss.ignore(3);
    iss >> quoted(s);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `s.length()-1` yields the length of the whole string except one character.

You should write for example

```
auto n = s.find("\"");

s = s.substr( n+1, s.length() - n - 2 );
```

Or you could write the following way

```
    auto n = s.find( '"' );
    s = s.substr( n + 1, s.rfind( '"' ) - n - 1 );
```